# Google Analytics - Track Products Through Checkout Flow

Tags: google-analytics

When the user goes to the Cart page, we have a CTA button that allows then to 'upgrade' their product to a more deluxe version. Whether they decide to upgrade or not, they will be sent to an Information page where they enter their credit card and account information. Finally, the will reach an Order Confirmation page.

I have already applied analytics to the 'upgrade' CTA button to track when they have used this feature. Now I am trying to track whether the user has successfully went through the entire checkout flow with the an upgraded product. I was thinking of tracking this with a Google Analytics Custom Dimension, but I am unsure if this will work. I was hoping to get feedback before I implement my idea.

Requirements:
Tracks if the user reaches the Order Confirmation page with an 'upgraded' product they have upgraded in the Cart page

Proposed Solution:
Fire a Custom Dimension when the user upgrades the product in the Cart page. I am unsure how to verify if the user reaches the Order Confirmation page with the 'upgraded' product though.

Answer (score 1):

The term your searching for is funnel with a goal at the end. Here is a direct link on how to setup this funnel.

[Tips for setting up Funnels](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#funnels)

Here is an example of the report you would see. You can track the users progress through the funnel, you can also track if the user drops off (red lines) or if they move back up the funnel. I do not have this shown in this example.
[image: Funnel]